# Remove non alpanumberic characters within doublequotes in a string - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

My input text looks like this :

```
answer_result = I don’t think we’ll still be doing "prompt engineering" in five years "i.e." figuring out how to hack the prompt by " ," adding one magic word to the "" end that changes everything  else. " What will always matter is the "1" quality of ideas.
```

I need to remove all the non-alphanumeric chars in double quotes. I need to retain  "prompt engineering", "i.e.",  "1" . All other needs to be removed.

My expected output :

```
I don’t think we’ll still be doing "prompt engineering" in five years "i.e." figuring out how to hack the prompt by adding one magic word to the end that changes everything  else. What will always matter is the "1" quality of ideas.
```

I attempted the following code to get the location of double quotes:

```
import re
double_quotes_locs = [m.start() for m in re.finditer('"', answer_result)]
to_be_deleted = []
single_quotes = []
for s in range(0,len(double_quotes_locs),2):
    try:
        if (double_quotes_locs[s+1] - double_quotes_locs[s]) <= 1:
            to_be_deleted.append((double_quotes_locs[s],double_quotes_locs[s+1]))
            continue
        else:          
            if re.match("^[A-Za-z0-9]+", answer_result[double_quotes_locs[s]+1:double_quotes_locs[s+1]]):
                continue
            else:
                to_be_deleted.append((double_quotes_locs[s],double_quotes_locs[s+1]))
    except IndexError:
        single_quotes.append(double_quotes_locs[s])
        break
```

Can any assist me how to proceed further?

Or even fresh solution for this problem is welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.sub`:

```
import re

answer_result = '''I don’t think we’ll still be doing "prompt engineering" in five years "i.e." figuring out how to hack the prompt by " ," adding one magic word to the "" end that changes everything  else. " What will always matter is the "1" quality of ideas.'''

res = re.sub(r'"[^A-Za-z0-9]*"', '', answer_result)
```

Output:

```
I don’t think we’ll still be doing "prompt engineering" in five years "i.e." figuring out how to hack the prompt by  adding one magic word to the  end that changes everything  else. " What will always matter is the "1" quality of ideas.
```

You can then use `re.sub` again to replace multiple consecutive white spaces with a single one.

Comment: Is it producing the expected output?

Comment: @mandy8055 I think it is answering the question "Remove non alpanumberic characters within doublequotes in a string".

Comment: I need to  remove a single doublequotes after else. too

Comment: Also, the solution works only for the text enclosed in ''' which is not my case. My text will be always in '

Comment: It works as long as you don't have single quotes in your string. Regarding your orphan quote, this is not something you can do with regex. You can iterate over your string and use a stack to check if your quotes are balanced... but you'll have to find a criteria to identify the orphan quote.